# Kubernetes - do I need to use https for container communication inside a pod?

Tags: networking, https, kubernetes, containers

Been googling it for a while and can't figure out the answer: suppose I have two containers inside a pod, and one has to send the other some secrets. Should I use https or is it safe to do it over http? If I understand correctly, the traffic inside a pod is firewalled anyway, so you can't eavesdrop on the traffic from outside the pod. So... no need for https?

Comment: Containers inside a Pod can communicate using `127.0.0.1`. Its secure unless you expose that port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Containers inside a Pod communicate using the loopback network interface, localhost.

TCP packets would get routed back at IP layer itself, if the address is localhost.

> It is implemented entirely within the operating system's networking software and passes no packets to any network interface controller. Any traffic that a computer program sends to a loopback IP address is simply and immediately passed back up the network software stack as if it had been received from another device.

So when communication among Containers inside a Pod, it is not possible to get hijacked/ altered.

If you want to understand more, take a look [understanding-kubernetes-networking](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727)

Hope it answers your question