# Converting HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Tags: http, https, proxy, reverse, envoyproxy

I have a need to make all existing End points of Microservices connection to move from HTTP to HTTPS, so that it meets a business need, with less over head.

For starters, I was looking at running Envoy as a Forward proxy, which would convert all outgoing HTTP transfer from the same local host to a HTTPS forward to its intended destination. On the intended destination, to avoid any application changes, I will also have a corresponding Envoy side car, but configured as a Reverse proxy, so that it translates the incoming HTTPS request to original HTTP End point for the application to work seamlessly.

Is this the best approach so far, as I am trying to implement solutions without touching any existing code, so that it could be expanded to all springboot Microservices

Comment: Your use of the terms forward and reverse is back to front, although, arguably both are really acting as reverse proxies. You have not explained the requirement therefore it is impossible to say if your solution is appropriate or optimal

Answer (score 1):

If I sum up what you want, you would like to implement something like this :

[image: Architecture]

There are two Envoy (named frontend and backend), communicating with each other in HTTPS. However, traffic coming to frontend and going from backend is unencrypted (HTTP). If your app only supports HTTP, then it is fine because you don't have to change anything in your code. It can be quite cumbersome to add a sidecar with the same configuration for every app (and the same TLS certs ?) but this is the price to pay.

I don't know where you are running your apps, but if you are running them in something like Kubernetes, then having unencrypted traffic between the backend Envoy and your app if they are both inside a pod is fine (based on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520864). Anyway, as long as the sidecar and the app communicates via `localhost`, then everything should be fine (https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44617).

Adding HTTPS inside your network is great because it prevents malicious users to eavesdrop your traffic. This may be out of the scope of the question but, from my perspective, adding HTTPS **only** inside your network is not enough. What happens if someone intercepts a request from your client to the frontend Envoy (HTTP, not encrypted) ? You may want to think about adding HTTPS support also to the frontend Envoy. There may be more risks to eavesdrop client requests from the Internet than inside your network if it is well designed.

Anyway, if you want to implement the schema above, then you can easily do this with Envoy :) It requires some configuration. Assuming frontend Envoy listens on 8080, backend Envoy listens on 8443, and your app listens on 5000, the following configuration can do the job :

Frontend Envoy config :

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: envoy-backend
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router

  clusters:
  - name: envoy-backend
    connect_timeout: 5s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: envoy-backend
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: envoy-backend
                port_value: 8443
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls # required to communicate in HTTPS
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
```

Backend Envoy config :

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8443
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: app
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls # TLS configuration
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/https.crt"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/key.pem"

  clusters:
  - name: app
    connect_timeout: 5s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: app
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1 # sidecar and app should communicate using localhost
                port_value: 5000
```

Comment: any idea how to do opposite? 
Like `client -> https -> envoy -> http -> backend`

Comment: @Puwka if you configure only the listener with TLS, then you could have `client -> https -> envoy -> http -> backend`. This is exactly what does the "Backend Envoy config" in my answer. In your case, you probably want to have a single envoy, with the "Backend Envoy config".